# Why do i get an SQL error when i have the right number of parameters and values for my statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm getting an SQL error saying "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

I'm aware this means that i don't have enough array keys to match the number of parameters in my SQL, but i can't work out why.

Here is the code and the output from the echoes and var_dumps

```
$email_address_array = array_map('trim', explode(',', $email_addresses));
$values = '';
$values_array = array(":email_body" => $email_body);
foreach($email_address_array as $email_address){
    if($values == ''){
        $values = "(".$_SESSION['userid'].", :".$email_address.", :email_body, '".$groups."', 0)";
    } else {
        $values .= ", (".$_SESSION['userid'].", :".$email_address.", :email_body, '".$groups."', 0)";
    }
    $values_array[':'.$email_address.''] = $email_address;
}

$sqlCreateMessage = "INSERT INTO messages 
                        (sender_id, recipients, message, message_group, draft) 
                    VALUES ".$values;

echo $sqlCreateMessage;
echo "<br>";
var_dump($values_array);
$stmt = $dbConn->prepare($sqlCreateMessage);

if($stmt->execute($values_array) === false){
    $msg = 'Error inserting the email into the database.';
    return false;
}else{
    $msg = "The email was logged";
    return true;
}
```

This is the SQL statement that gets the variables bound to:

```
INSERT INTO messages (sender_id, recipients, 
message, message_group, draft) VALUES (424, 
:k@gmail.com, :email_body, '', 0), (424, 
:peter@gmail.com, :email_body, '', 0), (424, 
:m@gmail.com, :email_body, '', 0)
```

This is the array with the values that get thrown into the SQL statement. I want :email_body to be identical for each row that gets inserted into the database. But i want the email addresses to be different for each one.

```
array(4) { 
    [":email_body"]=> string(2) "hi" 
    [":k@gmail.com"]=> string(11) "k@gmail.com" 
    [":peter@gmail.com"]=> string(15) "peter@gmail.com" 
    [":m@gmail.com"]=> string(11) "m@gmail.com" 
}
```

$email_addresses is just a string of email addresses seperated by: ', ' or ','

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have emulated prepares enabled?  If not, you cannot re-use the same named-parameter multiple times.

Comment: @PatrickQ What does that mean?

Comment: [See Here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#emulation) and search for it in the official documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php).

Comment: Do not use the email address for the parameter name. That will introduce all kinds of issues

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the following:

- this is probably an answer to your question - on every loop you define two placeholders (for `recipients` and `message` fields), but you add only one value in parameters array. So, you will have different count for the placeholders and the actual values if your `$email_address_array` array has more then one item
- use statement with constant placeholder's name, prepare this statement once and execute it multiple times. Now you are trying to generate one statement with all available values.

Next example shows this approach:

```
<?php
... 
#
$email_body = "...";
$groups = "...";

# SQL statement
$sqlCreateMessage = 
    "
    INSERT INTO messages (sender_id, recipients, message, message_group, draft)
    VALUES (:sender_id, :recipients, :message, :message_group, :draft)
    ";
echo $sqlCreateMessage;
echo "<br>";

# Prepare statement
$stmt = $dbConn->prepare($sqlCreateMessage);
// Check result from $dbConn->prepare - FALSE or PDOException, depending on error handling.

# Execute statement
$email_address_array = array_map('trim', explode(',', $email_addresses));
foreach($email_address_array as $email_address){
    $values_array = array(
        ":sender_id" => $_SESSION['userid'],
        ":recipients" => $email_address,
        ":message" => $email_body,
        ":message_group" => $groups,
        ":draft" => 0
    );
    if ($stmt->execute($values_array) === false){
        $msg = 'Error inserting the email into the database.';
        return false;
    } else {
        $msg = "The email was logged";
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to put different placeholders for each value. So i just hashed the email address for each placeholder.